# encontrar index en arreglo de objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un arreglo de objetos que se llena de manera aleatoria

```js
var lproducts = [
{
 "nombre":"Agua",
 "descripcion":"Agua purificada",
 "precio": 10.5
 },
{
"nombre":"leche",
 "descripcion":"leche entera",
 "precio": 20
 },
{
"nombre":"Manzana",
 "descripcion":"Manzana Roja",
 "precio": 5
 },
{
"nombre":"Galletas",
 "descripcion":"Galletas Chocolate",
 "precio": 10
 }
]
```

Yo no sé en que momento se agrega algún objeto al arreglo por lo que no sé su index, y quiero eliminar el objeto en que la propiedad nombre sea "Manzana". Sé que con `lproducts.splice(2, 1)` puedo eliminar un objeto del arreglo, donde el número 2 es el index del ítem que quiero eliminar.

Lo que yo necesito saber es el index del objeto con nombre manzana para poder eliminarlo.

Comment: intenta con un for y un if producto["nombre"]==manzana return i;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un map del array donde solo obtengas nombres de producto, ya con eso puedes usar `indexOf`

```js
var lproducts = [
{
 "nombre":"Agua",
 "descripcion":"Agua purificada",
 "precio": 10.5
 },
{
"nombre":"leche",
 "descripcion":"leche entera",
 "precio": 20
 },
{
"nombre":"Manzana",
 "descripcion":"Manzana Roja",
 "precio": 5
 },
{
"nombre":"Galletas",
 "descripcion":"Galletas Chocolate",
 "precio": 10
 }
]


var index = lproducts.map(producto => producto.nombre).indexOf("Manzana")
lproducts.splice(index, 1);


console.log(index)
console.log(lproducts)
```

Comment: con esto quedo resuelto. funciono a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar la funcion reduce() de la clase Array.

```
lproducts.reduce(function(anterior, actual, indice){ 
  if(anterior && anterior.nombre === "Manzana") return indice-1;
  if(actual.nombre === "Manzana") return indice;
})
```

Empieza recibiendo el primer elemento en `anterior`, el segundo en `actual` y el indice del actual en `indice`. Recorre asi todo el arreglo y si el valor de alguno coincide devuelve su índice.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría el método `filter()` o `find()`. Te pongo una función de búsqueda de prueba:

```
function getProductoByName(productos, nombre) {
    return productos.filter(
        function(producto){ return producto.nombre == nombre }
    );
}
```

A esta función le pasas por parámetro tu array (**lproducts**) y el nombre buscado (**Manzana**).

El método **filter()** devuelve un array con todos los elementos que pasan el test. En este caso, devuelve los productos cuya clave *nombre* es igual al *nombre* que le pasamos a la función.

```
getProductoByName(lproducts, 'Manzana')

{nombre: "Manzana", descripcion: "Manzana Roja", precio: 5}
```

NOTA: La diferencia entre los métodos **find()** y **filter()** es que (si hay resultados) **find()** devuelve el primer resultado encontrado y **filter()** devuelve un array con todos los resultados. Si en tu caso, *nombre* es una clave que no se puede repetir, puedes cambiar **filter()** por **find()**.

NOTA2: Si lo que necesitas es el índice, puedes usar otro método llamando **findIndex()**, similar a **find()**, pero devuelve el índice en vez del elemento.

NOTA3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value